# Strange Github username for my account

Tags: git, github

My github username is unionx. And I add my ssh pub-key to this account. But today I push code to my repo, the commiter has another username, recursionil.

I try to login with recursionil and unionx's password, it's logged in successfully. The account is blank and nothing on it. So I feel very strange.

I hope someone can help me figure out why this happened.

[image: I push 9 commits today.]

I checked the local repo commit log, the username is 'unionx'.

[image: local repo commit log]

**Result:**

Ok I know why now. 2 years ago I registered an account with the email I am using now. And I am using this email in my local git config. So github uses the email in the commit head to identify the commit user.

Solution: I deleted the user 'recursionil', and change my 'unionx's primary email to the email I am using now. So the commit log is reset to 'unionx'.

Comment: Your question lacks a question ;-)

Comment: checking your logs, all commits since August 2013 have been from recursionil... and recursionil joined August 2012.. must later than your original commit... with the exact same avatar.. very dubious...   @TimCastelijns  excellent point...

Comment: Yes, the avatars are same. And I can log in with unionx's password. I updated the information and my local username is 'unionx'.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user
Didn't you register recursionil two year ago?

Comment: Oh, I login github with unionx@foxmail.com, it's recursionil!

Comment: @unionx ok I have included in my answer the importance of the email used.

Comment: @VonC Thx! Speaking of github using the email in commit head to identify the user, I think perhaps ssh key is better for this?

Comment: @unionx no, name and emails are part of the history, and can be interpreted by any Git hosting service (combined with gravatar, a service that one of the founder of GitHub made before creating GitHub: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Preston-Werner#Career). Your ssh key, on the other hand, is private.

Answer (score -1):

Check your git config: you should see a `user.name` equals to `recursionil` (and a `user.email` with your email).

The email is important, so changing it (as the OP mention) can help Github choose the right account.

If you change it back to `unionx`:

```
git config user.name unionx
```

And push a new commit, it should be authored as your original account.

I guess around August 2013, a "wrong" user.name was set, and I don't know how that second account was created, though.

Comment: Thx, but I checked this, and it's unionx, not recursionil. I think I never set it to recursionil.

Comment: @unionx then, if you are using ssh url, try and change your ssh key on your unionx account. Or try using an https url: `git remote set-url origin https://unionx@github.com/unionx/unionx-emacs-config`